# what's the size of my logs in cloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to know the actual size of my logs and how fast do they grow.
Looking at Cloudwatch>Metrics>Account>IncomingBytes and choosing that I want to get the SUM for:

- last 3 months and a period of 30 Days I do get 43GB, but for a period of 7 days I do get 17 GB and for a period of 1 Day 45 MB
- last 4 weeks and a period of 30 days I do get 63GB, but for a period of 7 days I have 784KB, and a period of 1 day 785 KB.

I do not understand It, how could I get the size of my logs right now? and how to find how it increases over time (for example 1 day?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the cloudwatch configuration (Graph options), there latest value was selected and should be the"time range value".

After changing It Cloudwatch was showing me that I have some TB and modifying the period was always showing the same values
[image: Graph options]

Answer (score 2):

CloudWatch logs doesn't [publish a metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatch-Logs-Monitoring-CloudWatch-Metrics.html) for "bytes right now." And a sum of `IncomingBytes` will just show the bytes received in whatever period you look at; it doesn't account for existing bytes or bytes that are removed due to a retention policy or deleted stream.

However, you can get the current *reported* bytes from the log group description. Here's a Python program that iterates all log groups and prints the answer:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('logs')

paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
for page in paginator.paginate():
    for group in page['logGroups']:
        print(f"{group['logGroupName']}: {group['storedBytes']}")
```

If it's important to track this over time, I'd wrap it in a Lambda that runs nightly (or however often you want) and reports the number as a [custom metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html).